# Another missing concept on derivatives

Tags: calculus

For the equation $y=x^{8x^2+6x}$ MathJax doesn't seem to make the $8x^2+6x$ look like an exponent but it is an exponent on $x$, ***why*** doesn't it work to assign $u=8x^2+6x$ and get $y=x^u$ so that the derivative of y=$ux^{u-1}du/dx$ and that would simply equal $(8x^2-6x)x^{8x^2+6x-1}(16x+6)$.  Trying to answer my own question I would think maybe the answer is $u$ is ***not*** a different variable than $x$ , but I'm on shaky theoretical ground here so wanted to hear why that doesn't work.

I see how to do this problem if I take the natural log of both sides and then differentiate.  Of course that gives a completely different (and correct) answer.

Comment: do you mean for MathJax or the answer to my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that the rule $\frac{d}{dx}(x^k) = k\cdot x^{k-1}$ only works if $k$ is a constant, but not if it is a function. It's a bit like $\frac{d}{dx} a^x \neq x\cdot a^{x-1}$, but you have to apply the rule differentiating exponential functions.

The problem with differentiating $x^{u(x)}$ is that it is a mixture of both cases. To differentiate, you have to rewrite it as
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^{u(x)}) = \frac{d}{dx} (\exp(\log(x)\cdot u(x)))$$
and now you can apply the chain rule:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \exp(\log x \cdot u(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}(\log x\cdot u(x)) \cdot \exp(\log x\cdot u(x)) \\ = \left(\frac{u(x)}{x} + \log x \cdot u'(x)\right)\cdot \exp(\log x\cdot u(x)).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very miuch.  I see this now and now it makes sense why I have to use logs.